# I can only help you so much, What's up with the order?

Tags: word-order, so

> **I can only help you so much.**

I know ***only so much*** means the a limited amount.

So, I know that means there's a limit to how much I can help you.

But, the problem is "the order". Why ***only help you so much***, not ***help you only so much***?

I don't get it. this makes me get mixed up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both ***only help you so much*** and ***help you only so much*** are grammatical. This is because "only" is an adverb, and adverbs can usually be placed anywhere in a sentence.

You are right to feel confused, though, because "only" can mean very different things depending on where it is located in the sentence. ***Help you only so much*** is likely the intended meaning, because "only" modifies "so much." In casual English, ***only help you so much*** is acceptable, because you would just infer that "only" modifies "so much" and not "help." Adverbs are often misplaced in spoken English.

Here is a web page that discusses this common problem with "only": https://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/%E2%80%9Conly%E2%80%9D-the-most-insidious-misplaced-modifier